# Android SDK: I'm re-installing SDK which versions to choose?

Tags: android

hi I'm reinstalling the SDK again due to it falling apart on sdk tools rev 20 upgrade. And I was wondering out of all the options which ones should I be installing. I note that [link here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) Api 10 2.3.3 is the most popular. but whenit comes to installing my SDK to start coding, if I just wanted to release for this verison should I just select this option for install? I would assume that all new version would be compatible with earlier revisions, is this the case, so coding against API 10 would enable anyone from API10-latest to use the software? if this is the case isn't it worth coding against the lowest API?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the same Android version as you have on your own mobile device.

Comment: yeah this is the way I've been doing it, can I assume all future (higher) API verisons will be compatible in this case?

Comment: @Purplemonkey Whatever you have developed for version A will be, in general, running fine on version B > A. Not really always, but compatibility problems are, in general, easy to solve

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest 2.3.3, 3.2, 4.0.3, 4.1.
Other Libraries you should install are Android Support Library, Google AdMob Ad SDK, Google Play APK Expansion Library,Google Play Licensing Library, Google USB Driver and Google Web Driver.

Answer (score 0):

My preferences are `2.2, 2.3.3, 4.0.3, 4.1`.
For extra libs: `Google USB Driver, Android Support Library, Google AdMob Ad SDK, Google Play APK Expansion Library, Google Web Driver`.

It just depends on your target platforms where you will deploy your products.